# Mysql Procedure takes time to insert using select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, stored-procedures, insert

```
/**
        STEP 1: Get all the valid information and store in temp historic data ---- DONE
        STEP 2: If any values are 0 or missing 
        STEP 3: Reduce the count of data-points from default(8)
        STEP 4: Calculate Average of all the datapoints
        STEP 5: Calculate Sigma
    */

DECLARE prev_year_date, prev_prev_year_date date;
DECLARE data_points, calculation_weeks, prev_year, prev_prev_year int;
    DECLARE days_in_week int;
    /* Since the number of days in a week will always be constant (7), using a static value */
    SET days_in_week = 7;

    /* Fetching all the constants from the configuration */

truncate table ro_temp_historic_data; 
truncate table average_volume;
truncate table sigma;
truncate table range1;
truncate table range2;
truncate table  expected_volume;
truncate table  mean_result;
truncate table  previous_week_volume;
truncate table  current_week_volume;
truncate table  final_paf_data;
truncate table  paf_score;
truncate table market_ms;
truncate table change_in_ms;


   INSERT INTO ro_temp_historic_data
        SELECT r.ro_id, date_inserted, IF(fuel_type = 'ms', actual_volume_ms, actual_volume_hsd) as actual_volume, YEAR(date_inserted),user_id,start_date
        FROM retail_outlets ro
        left outer JOIN  volume_trackers r
        ON ro.ro_id = r.ro_id
        WHERE (
            (r.date_inserted >=(DATE_SUB((ro.historic_end_date), INTERVAL ((8 * 7) - 1) DAY))
            AND r.date_inserted <= ro.historic_end_date)
            OR
            (
                r.date_inserted >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB((ro.historic_end_date), INTERVAL 364 DAY), INTERVAL ((8 * 7) - 1) DAY)
                AND r.date_inserted <= DATE_SUB((ro.historic_end_date), INTERVAL 364 DAY))
            OR
            (
                r.date_inserted >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB((ro.historic_end_date), INTERVAL 728 DAY), INTERVAL ((8 * 7) - 1) DAY)
                AND r.date_inserted <= DATE_SUB((ro.historic_end_date), INTERVAL 728 DAY)))

            and ro.pricing_module=1 and if (fuel_type='ms',ro.ms,ro.hsd)=1;


    insert into average_volume
            select 
            a.ro_id,sum(a.actual_volume)/count(a.ro_id) age_volume,
            (count(a.ro_id))datapoints,user_id,start_date,year 
            from ro_temp_historic_data a 
                where a.generated_by = user_id 
                and a.start_date = start_date
                and a.actual_volume !=0
                group by a.ro_id,a.year;


    insert into sigma 

            select 
            a.ro_id,sqrt(sum(power((a.average_volume-d.actual_volume),2)/(a.datapoints-1))) sigma,a.average_volume,user_id,start_date,a.cur_year
            from average_volume a,ro_temp_historic_data d 
                where a.ro_id=d.ro_id and
                (a.start_date=start_date and
                a.user_id=user_id and
                a.cur_year=d.year) and 
                d.actual_volume !=0
                group by a.ro_id,a.cur_year,a.average_volume;



END
```

I have this procedure which is taking 3-4 minutes to run. The output of each insert is used in the following insert query thus i have to save it. It searches in around 5 million data and the final result is around 70 000 rows.

I have indexed the table and even created partitions but nothing has helped

```
Ro_temp_historic_data:Contains index on ro_id and year
'ro_id', 'int(11)', 'YES', 'MUL', NULL, ''
'date_inserted', 'date', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'actual_volume', 'float', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'year', 'varchar(10)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'generated_by', 'int(11)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''


Average_volume contains indexes on ro_id
'ro_id', 'int(11)', 'YES', 'MUL', NULL, ''
'average_volume', 'float', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'datapoints', 'int(11)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'user_id', 'int(11)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'start_date', 'date', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'cur_year', 'int(11)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''

'start_date', 'date', 'YES', '', NULL, ''

Sigma contains index on ro_id
'ro_id', 'int(11)', 'YES', 'MUL', NULL, ''
'sigma', 'float', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'average_volume', 'float', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'user_id', 'int(11)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'start_date', 'date', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'year', 'int(11)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
```

Comment: One minute is a relative thing; how many records roughly are you inserting?

Comment: well the thing is my other query depends on this result and thus it affects them too.It inserts roughly around 70000 records..the query is actually used in a procedure which in whole is taking more than a minute as this query takes around 1 minute to run

Comment: I would think that one minute for 70,000 records is not unreasonable. That's 1166 records inserted per seconds.

Comment: I have Changed My question with the whole code now

Comment: You can post the table definitions, and what user_id is and where it comes from. Indexing is only useful if the index is used. It's difficult to explain these queries, so probably it's a good idea to use EXPLAIN on the individual select-queries.

Comment: I have added the table definitons and the columns which i have indexed